# let ajax data give timeout jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

ive got the net function:

```
            var timeout=60000;
    setInterval(function() {

        $.ajax({
          url: "/xheresfm/getstatus.php",
          data: {
          },
          success: function( data ) {
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            timeout=obj.refresh;
          }
        })
    }, timeout);
});
```

The timeoit is allways 60000, but obj.refresh don't give an empty result, i cant figure out whit it doesn't work.

for example if obj.refresh is 9999999, the timeout is still 60000

Comment: what happens when you remove the second word `var`?

Comment: no differance still 6000

Comment: Can you confirm the error still exists with the newly edited code?

Comment: yes if it is above the code like in the example above than it still is 6000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your code is not working is that you are using asynchronous call, timout method executes before AJAX call. You can overcome this by using the below code:

```
var timeout=60000;

var func = function() {
        $.ajax({
          url: "/xheresfm/getstatus.php",
          data: {
          },
          success: function( data ) {
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            timeout=obj.refresh;

            setTimeout(func, timeout);
          }
        })
    }

func();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use interval cause if performance issues - it will call and call, call ... call, loop, loooop^^ - not a good idea. What do you think about my approach?

```
var timeout = 60000;

var refreshStatus = function() {
        $.ajax({
          url: "/xheresfm/getstatus.php",
          success: function( data ) {
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

            //do stuff on success
          },
          done: function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
               refreshStatus();
            }, timeout);

          }
        })
    }

refreshStatus();
```